# Can I take my infant (US citizen) with me to a US visa interview?

Tags: children

I and my wife will be attending a L1a / L2 visa interview(extension) in Chennai next week.

We have a 1 year old who was born in US and hence a citizen. Can we take her to the consulate? We don't have a place to baby sit her.

Comment: It is perfectly alright to do so.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? They may even have facilities to feed her and/or staff to look after the child while you're in your interview.

Comment: How did it go? I have a feeling they wouldn't allow this but no official source. It is even possible it's not explicitly allowed but the facility would just let it slip.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is allowed, but be sure to check your countries U.S Consulate website but this should be consistent:

> Please note, only those with an appointment will be admitted to the Embassy. Young children accompanying the person with an appointment can also come in, as can the parents or guardian of a minor who has an appointment.

([U.S. Consulate in London](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/niv-london/))